# Explode not limiting?

Tags: php, explode

I created a script to limit a text if a user is not signed in. I get the text from file_get_contents. I am telling you this to explain the variables.
My code should explode the text with a limit and echo it back with a for loop. 
My problem is that, whatever limit I try, it will still display the full text. Right now, I don't care about tips or tricks, unless they are completely relevant to having a limit on my text. I just want to know why it is not limiting. Enough chatter, here is the code.

```
$words=explode(" ", $storytext, 150);
$count1 = count($words);
$count = $count1 - 1;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++){
echo $words[$i];
echo " ";
}
```

Thank you in advanced, andy

**EDIT**

Story text is the file_get_contents part. I forgot to clean my code since I changed wordcount in my code. Thank you, wesolyromek and Simeon, for answering my question. Code is perfect now. Mucho Gracias

Comment: It was my first variable for $words. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: You should limit your `for` loop then, not the explode() parts. You see the last `$word[149]` will not just contain a word, but the remainder of your text input.

Answer (score 2):

According to PHP.net

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

> If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.

You should display the array without it's last element (last index), because it contains the rest of the text. Just limit the for loop to:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
```

and it should work fine. Moreover, please use indentation. It makes the code much easier to read ;)

Answer (score 1):

The last element of an explode always contains the rest of the string.

Change this line:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++){
```

remove the '=' so the last Element will not be displayed and you'll end up with the correct limit.

Edit: Guess I was a few seconds behind wesolyromek ^^